# Decreasing the time delay for diacritic marks menu appearance

Tags: keyboard, macos, internationalization

On my iMac, when one pushes certain character keys after about 1 second a menu appears with the selected character with diacritic marks (accents) - i.e. when one presses <kbd>S</kbd>, one is presented with a menu showing `ß ś š`. You can then choose to insert one of these characters using the numerical keys (i.e. pressing <kbd>S</kbd> ... short wait ... press <kbd>1</kbd> results in a `ß`).

[image]

(I'm not sure if this is the default macOS behaviour, or a setting for my Mac. The keyboard in System Preferences implies that holding a key should repeat that key because it has "Key Repeat" and "Delay Until Repeat" settings.)

Is it possible to decrease this wait time? I've been typing in German a lot recently, and ending up with `a4` in my text when I intend to write `ä`.

Comment: The popup accent menu is default behavior since 10.7 in 2011.